# How to get the DisconnectTimestamp from Amazon Connect call in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, amazon-connect, call-recording

My call recordings are being pushed at S3 and stored with `contactId_timestamp.wav` as filename.
For now i can get/download the files by specifically providing the file name as `key`, now i wanted to create the filename by myself as `contactId + disconnecttimestamp` i can get ge contactId through `getContactId()` but how to get the `disconnecttimestamp`?

My goal is same what we are experiencing in `Contact Flow Search` the recordings can be played with respect to contactId.

Here is how i am downloading the recordings from S3.

```
require("dotenv").config();
const expres = require("express");
const app = expres();

app.listen(3001);

const aws = require("aws-sdk");

aws.config.update({
    secretAccessKey: process.env.ACCESS_SECRET,
    accessKeyId: process.env.ACCESS_KEY,
    region: process.env.REGION
})

const BUCKET = process.env.BUCKET
const s3 = new aws.S3(secretAccessKey = process.env.ACCESS_SECRET, accessKeyId = process.env.ACCESS_KEY);

 app.get("/download/filename", async(req, res)=>{
    const filename = req.params.filename
    let x = await s3.getObject({Bucket:BUCKET, Key:filename}).promise();
    res.send(x.Body);
})
```

And Than hitting the `http://localhost:3001/download/0989c085-16d1-478b-8858-1ccddb2990f4_20220303T16:46_UTC.wav`

Answer (score 0):

If you have the ContactID for the call you can use describeContact to get the contact info which includes the DisconnectTimestamp.

Something along these lines should work.

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

aws.config.update({
    secretAccessKey: process.env.ACCESS_SECRET,
    accessKeyId: process.env.ACCESS_KEY,
    region: process.env.REGION
})
const connect = new AWS.Connect({ region: process.env.REGION });

var params = {
  ContactId: 'STRING_VALUE', /* required */
  InstanceId: 'STRING_VALUE' /* required - the connect instance ID */
};

connect.describeContact(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else var DisconnectTimestamp = data.Contact.DisconnectTimestamp);           // successful response
});
```

more info here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Connect.html#describeContact-property